# How to pass a constant array literal to a function that takes a pointer without using a variable C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, function

If I have a prototype that looks like this:

```
function(float,float,float,float)
```

I can pass values like this:

```
function(1,2,3,4);
```

So if my prototype is this:

```
function(float*);
```

Is there any way I can achieve something like this?

```
function( {1,2,3,4} );
```

Just looking for a lazy way to do this without creating a temporary variable, but I can't seem to nail the syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I suppose I expected quick and dirty answers for a quick and dirty question, but your response explored some alternative styles I hadn't thought of.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do it in C99 (but *not* ANSI C (C90) or any current variant of C++) with *compound literals*.  See section 6.5.2.5 of the C99 standard for the gory details.  Here's an example:

```
// f is a static array of at least 4 floats
void foo(float f[static 4])
{
   ...
}

int main(void)
{
    foo((float[4]){1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f});  // OK
    foo((float[5]){1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f});  // also OK, fifth element is ignored
    foo((float[3]){1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f});  // error, although the GCC doesn't complain
    return 0;
}
```

GCC also provides this as an extension to C90.  If you compile with `-std=gnu90` (the default), `-std=c99`, or `-std=gnu99`, it will compile; if you compile with `-std=c90`, it will not.

Comment: One could obviously also compile with `-std=gnu89` (but not `-std=c89`), as it is synonymous with `-std=gnu90` (and `-std=c90`) (I'm sure you know this Adam, it's more for others in case they didn't :P).

Comment: This is not good solution, because you will not be the length of the arguments passed.

Answer (score 19):

This is marked both C and C++, so you're gonna get radically different answers.

If you are expecting four parameters, you can do this:

```
void foo(float f[])
{
    float f0 = f[0];
    float f1 = f[1];
    float f2 = f[2];
    float f3 = f[3];
}

int main(void)
{
    float f[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    foo(f);
}
```

But that is rather unsafe, as you could do this by accident:

```
void foo(float f[])
{
    float f0 = f[0];
    float f1 = f[1];
    float f2 = f[2];
    float f3 = f[3];
}

int main(void)
{
    float f[] = {1, 2}; // uh-oh
    foo(f);
}
```

It is usually best to leave them as individual parameters. Since you shouldn't be using raw arrays anyway, you can do this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

void foo(std::vector<float> f)
{
    assert(f.size() == 4);

    float f0 = f[0];
    float f1 = f[1];
    float f2 = f[2];
    float f3 = f[3];
}

int main(void)
{
    float f[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    foo(std::vector<float>(f, f + 4)); // be explicit about size

    // assert says you cannot do this:
    foo(std::vector<float>(f, f + 2));
}
```

An improvement, but not much of one. You could use [`boost::array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/array.html), but rather than an error for mismatched size, they are initialized to 0:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>

void foo(boost::array<float, 4> f)
{
    float f0 = f[0];
    float f1 = f[1];
    float f2 = f[2];
    float f3 = f[3];
}

int main(void)
{
    boost::array<float, 4> f = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    foo(f);

    boost::array<float, 4> f2 = {1, 2}; // same as = {1, 2, 0, 0}
    foo(f2);
}
```

This will all be fixed in C++0x, when initializer list constructors are added:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

void foo(std::vector<float> f)
{
    assert(f.size() == 4);

    float f0 = f[0];
    float f1 = f[1];
    float f2 = f[2];
    float f3 = f[3];
}

int main(void)
{
    foo({1, 2, 3, 4}); // yay, construct vector from this

    // assert says you cannot do this:
    foo({1, 2});
}
```

And probably `boost::array` as well:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>

void foo(boost::array<float, 4> f)
{
    float f0 = f[0];
    float f1 = f[1];
    float f2 = f[2];
    float f3 = f[3];
}

int main(void)
{
    foo({1, 2, 3, 4});

    foo({1, 2}); // same as = {1, 2, 0, 0} ..? I'm not sure,
                 // I don't know if they will do the check, if possible.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a compound literal:

```
function ((float[2]){2.0, 4.0});
```

Although, I'm not sure why you want to go through the trouble. This is not permitted by ISO.

Generally, shortcuts like this should be avoided in favor of readability in all cases; laziness is not a good habit to explore (personal opinion, of course)

Comment: I agree about the readability, and in practice this particular function will be passed a memory address and be happy.  However, during testing I often want to just plug in some random values.  Your snippet does the trick, for better or worse :)  Thanks!

Comment: C99 is "ISO" and allows compound literals in the standard. It's just not available on C90, nor portable to C++.

Comment: I'd argue that in some cases this improves readability.

Answer (score 3):

You can technically take reference to array, but you still can't create anonymous initializer list I think.

```
void func(int (&bla)[4])
{
    int count = sizeof(bla)/sizeof(bla[0]);
    // count == 4
}

int bla[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
func(bla);

int bla1[] = {1, 2};
func(bla1); // <-- fails
```

For C++ way, look at [boost::assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html). Pretty neat way of filling in STL containers.

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is that there is no syntax for that.  The good news is that this will change with the next official version of the C++ standard (due in the next year or two).  The new syntax will look exactly as you describe.

Comment: heh heh, next year or two :]  Good to know this will be in C++0x.

Comment: I doubt in two years. Beta 10 of Visual studio already has some C++0x features built in, and g++ 4.4 already has initializer lists (http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). It was pushed back to 2010, probably first quarter.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can pass `std::array{ 1,2,3,4 }.data()`.

`std::array{...}` creates a temporary array with a deduced element type, and `.data()` returns a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Nice. A pity about the need to #include the array header.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. I do not have the standard available here, so I cannot give an exact reference, but the closest thing to what you ask for is string constants, i.e.

```
function(char *);
function("mystring");
```

is treated by the compiler as

```
char * some_pointer = "mystring";
function(char *);
function(some_pointer);
```

There is no way for other types of variables to be treated this way.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it only works with character arrays:

```
void func2(char arg[]) {
}

int main()
{   
    func2("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a builder class that would allow for about the same syntax

```
// roughly
template <typename C>
class Builder {
public:
   template <typename T>
   Builder(const T & _data) { C.push_back(_data); }
   template <typename T>
   Builder& operator()(const T & _data) { 
       C.push_back(_data);
       return *this;
    }
   operator const C & () const { return data; }
private:
   C data;

};
```

this way, you can use the class as

foo( const std::vector & v);

foo( Builder< std::vector >(1)(2)(3)(4) );

Answer (score 0):

To add to the fun, you can use templates to make it variable in length.

```
template<std::size_t N>
int chars(const char(&r)[N]){
    std::cout << N << ": " << r << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template<std::size_t N>
int floats(const float(&r)[N]){
    std::cout << N << ":";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << " " << r[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    chars("test");
    floats({1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f});
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can bind a `const` reference to a temporary. So if you don't need to write to the location, this will work:

```
void foo(const float (&a1)[4])  // clang needs the 4
{
}

foo((float[]){1,2,3,4});
```

Comment: `(float[]){1,2,3,4}` is a C-only feature.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Interesting. I expect you know that both g++ and clang++ are happy to compile it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: And MSVC doesn't. I too would like to live in an universe where MSVC doesn't exist, but it alas. Also I for one build with `-pedantic-errors`, which makes both GCC and Clang reject it. Sometimes extensions are useful, but here there's a standard alternative (see my answer), so there's little reason not to use them.

Answer (score -1):

I asked OpenAI Codex, and it suggested this method:

```c
func((uint8_t *) "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc")
```

and it works in embedded C90, while the compound literals did not (`syntax error near '{', expected 'sizeof'`).

Not really much benefit compared to creating a local scoped array, though:

```c
{
    uint8 da[6] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x9a, 0xbc};
    func(da);
}
```