# sending more than integer to the C++ function as parameter

Tags: c++, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing a constant array to a function in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269568/passing-a-constant-array-to-a-function-in-c-c)

```
void Bar (int *values) {}

void Foo ()
{
    int values[3] = { -5, 2, 8};
    Bar (values);
}
```

But i want something like the following. How can i make this possible?

```
void Foo ()
{
    Bar ({5,2,8}); //error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
}
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269568/passing-a-constant-array-to-a-function-in-c-c).

Comment: another similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161790/initialize-a-const-array-in-a-class-initializer-in-c