# Array too many initializer values

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function declaration as follows

```
void set_values(float values[4][4]);
```

If I call the function like this everything is OK.

```
float values[4][4] = {
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 } 
};
mat1.set_values(values);
```

However i thought that I could take the array declared in the curly braces and pass it directly into the function like this:

```
    mat1.set_values({
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 } 
    });
```

But this gives me a compile error `too many initializer values`

Why does the first code work but not the second one?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269568/how-to-pass-a-constant-array-literal-to-a-function-that-takes-a-pointer-without

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537349/initialiser-list-passed-as-function-parameter-for-array

Comment: You need to specify you are passing a float. such as 1.0f

Comment: @JoshAdams No you don't.  `int` to `float` is okay.

Comment: Must it be a raw array?

Comment: if you dont mind changing the signature of the function: [this works](https://ideone.com/RFq9p1)

Comment: No it doesn't have to be a raw array but I want to understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function expects an array object, not an initialization list for such an object.