# Char and double pointers declaration

Tags: c, pointers

I´m starting with C programing language and I have a doubt with the initialization of pointers. I know that when we declare a pointer we are reserving memory for the specific pointer, but this pointer may point to x address we don´t know anything about, the point is that I can do this:
 `char * s = "Hi";` but I can´t do this `double * f = 3;` so what I do to "initialize" this double pointer is the next piece of code:

```
double * d;
double x = 3;
d = &x;
```

So that I have the pointer pointing to an specific memory location with the initial value I want to have.

Summing up, my doubt is:

1.- Is there any way to initialize double/int pointers as with char ones?

Comment: I think the best you can do is declare the pointer after the declaration of `x`.  Then you can initialize the pointer to `&x` when you declare it, e.g. `double *d = &x;`

Comment: @TomKarzes and do you know why the char pointer initialization I wrote works, `char * s = "Hi";` but `double * f = 3;` does not?

Comment: String constants (in that context) are actually arrays whose elements have type `char`.  So for instance, `"abc"` has type `char [4]` (the fourth character is the terminating null character).  Compare with the character constant `'a'`, which has type `int`.

Comment: @TomKarzes so if I understand right, the syntax I wrote for initializing the String with the char pointer is an "special" syntax of C in order not to initialize an array of chars and initialize the indexes of that array that will contain the chars of the String

Comment: The string declaration is basically doing pointer assignment.  The string constant degrades to a `char *` in that context.  You can think of these as assignments.  You can assign one pointer to another, or an array to a pointer (in which case the array degrades to a pointer), but you can't assign an integer to a pointer.  If you could write `{3.0}` and have it implicitly create a `double [1]` array that's initialized to `{3.0}`, then that would work, but C only supports that when used to initialize an array.  String constants are special in that regard.

Comment: @TomKarzes: C does not support that only when used to initialize an array. One can write “(double []) { 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 }” to create an array of `double` in the middle of an expression, including when initializing a pointer, as my answer shows.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, I guess that was added with C99 (and prior to that as a gnu extension to C90).  I saw it described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269568/how-to-pass-a-constant-array-literal-to-a-function-that-takes-a-pointer-without).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you usually should not:

```
double *x = (double []) {3};
```

Just as `char *x = "Hi";` creates an array of `char` and initializes `x` to point to the first member of the array, the code above creates an array of `double` and initializes `x` to point its first member. (I have shown only a single element, but you could write more.) This is called a compound literal.

An important difference is that the lifetime of a string literal is the entire execution of the program, so you can safely return its address from a function. In contrast, a compound literal inside a function exists only as long as the function is executing, so its address cannot be returned from the function. If this definition appeared outside a function, the compound literal would exist for the entire execution of the program.

Compound literals are useful at times, but the situations where it is good to initialize a pointer to the address of a compound literal as I show above are very limited. Code like that should be used with restraint and discretion.

Answer (score 2):

The best you could do would be to use an array instead of a raw pointer. Since the array degrades to a pointer in almost every use case, it will *behave* roughly the way you want.

```
double d[] = {3};
```

will allocate the space (globally or on the stack, depending on whether it's performed at global or function scope) and initialize it at once. For almost all purposes, referring to `d` will cause it to degrade to a `double*`.

The main difference is that, for stack allocated arrays (function scope, without `static` qualifier), the array only lives until the end of the function call. Declaring it as `static double d[] = {3};` will make it live for the life of the program, but it will have a single initialization, and any changes will persist indefinitely.

The other important distinction is that you can't modify the address, since it's not *really* a pointer; `++d` won't be legal, since `d` is an array, not a pointer.

For an exact equivalent of `char *s = "Hi";`, you're basically stuck with a two-liner. That code is roughly equivalent to:

```
static char unnamed[] = {'H', 'i', '\0'};
char *s = unnamed;
```

It's a special behavior of C string literals, which no other type has direct language support for. Mimicking it precisely with `double` would always be a two liner:

```
static double dstorage[] = {3};
double *d = dstorage;
```